# Deleting the text from text fields by triggering the keypress event for backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete data from a content-editable div, on click event of a button.  I want this button to actually behave as backspace button. is that feasible ? Expecting sample code for this. 
I found [this.](http://bililite.com/blog/2011/01/23/improved-sendkeys/)

But it is not working for me . can anyone help please ?

I tried this also:

I tried the keypress events first to manually trigger the event for backspace :

```
    var press = jQuery.Event("keyup");
    press.ctrlKey = false;
    press.which = 8;
    press.keyCode = 8;
    $("#myDiv").trigger(press);
```

It triggers the event but not actually updating.

Comment: Do you have some of your own code you've tried out?

Comment: Users already have a backspace button on their keyboard. How will duplicating this functionality improve their experience?

Comment: I tried the keypress events first to manually trigger the event for backspace :

Comment: I updated the question for what i tried . Actually i am creating a custom keyboard & for that this functionality required.

Answer (score 0):

An event triggered by Javascript (with `element.dispatchEvent` or jQuery's `trigger`) is called "untrusted" and is sent to the event handler with `Event.isTrusted` set to `false`. The documentation on this is near-impossible to find; look at www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#h3_trusted-events. What this means is that the default action for that event *will not occur*: keypress events do not enter text. The element never sees your backspace event. The handlers that you attached in Javascript will work, just not the built-in effects.

Honestly, I do not see what the security advantage of this is, but that's the way modern browsers work.

I have a library that simulates keypresses; see [my sendkeys plugin](http://bililite.com/blog/2011/01/23/improved-sendkeys/).
The code is on [github](https://github.com/dwachss/bililiteRange): get the files `bililiteRange.js` and `jquery.sendkeys.js`.

After including those two files, you can do: `$("#myDiv").sendkeys("{backspace}")` and it should work.